# Symfony Dynamic class names are not allowed in compile-time

Tags: forms, symfony

I am trying to initialize dynamically a form. The form name is stored in $obj->getFormTypeName().

```
$formName = 'Acme\testBundle\Form\CustomType\\'.ucfirst($obj->getFormTypeName()).'Type';
$contactForms[$obj->getId()] = $this->createForm($formName::class);
```

But I get the error : `Compile Error: Dynamic class names are not allowed in compile-time ::class fetch`

Is there a way to initialize dynamically a form with the Scope Resolution Operator in Symfony ?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: with a static array having as key the value of `$obj->getFormTypeName()` and as value the corrispondent class

Comment: `::class` is just a shortcut to the class name that you have generated with `$formName = ...`. Why not just use `$formName`?

Comment: Thank you @qooplmao . qooplmao is right

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get around this issue, I'd do something like:

```
$contactForms[$obj->getId()] = $this->createForm(
    'Acme\\testBundle\\Form\\CustomType\\' . ucfirst($obj->getFormTypeName()) . 'Type'
);
```

After all, ::class only returns the fully qualified name of the class.

Comment: Looks good however, I would move path and type to the constants.

Comment: Thank you, although it is not immediately obvious , that you removed only the `::class` part from the row. To know also for the general cases, where it is not necesarilly connected to Symfony, as it is a general php error.

Answer (score 0):

One should not want to call a `::class` on a variable, string name of the class eg.
`Acme\testBundle\Form\CustomType\FormType` like this

`'Acme\testBundle\Form\CustomType\'::class`, as in the end the string var of the class, it's the classname itself.

Something similar is possible only in Javascript to my knowledge `'stringContents'.val()`